# Selecting anchor child of list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to select in the DOM the anchor link that is a direct child of my list item "dropdown-nav. It should change the link when the list item is clicked but doesn't. The active class applies perfectly. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-nav");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active-hit");
    this.find("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown-nav">
    <a href="/about">About
      <span class="nav-desc">Our company</span>
    </a>
    <div class="hide-border"></div>
    <ul class="second-tier">
      <div class="hide-corner"></div>
      <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our People</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work with us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">High Value Manufacturing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You included jQuery so you may update your code to simply use jQuery like this:

```js
$(".dropdown-nav").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active-hit');
  $(this).find('a').attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
})
```

```css
.active-hit {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown-nav">
    <a href="/about">About
      <span class="nav-desc">Our company</span>
    </a>
    <div class="hide-border"></div>
    <ul class="second-tier">
      <div class="hide-corner"></div>
      <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our People</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work with us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">High Value Manufacturing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not jQuery object. Replace this line:

```
this.find("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```

With this (this will change href of first link, if you need to change all of them, then iterate):

```
this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com/');
```

If you have included jQuery, you can do this too:

```
$(this).find("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```